# How to add a rounding constraint which takes floor value of 2 floats decision variable - Gurobi

Tags: linear-programming, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

Is there a way to introduce a rounding constraint, something on the following lines : `v = floor(x * y)`, where `x, y` are continuous decision variables and `v` is an integer decision variable. Essentially want to cast multiplication of continuous decision variable to integer. I am using Gurobi solver.

Answer (score 2):

Above can be achieved by adding following inequality constraints:

```
v <= x*y <= v + 1
```

With help of above inequalities, `v` would be rounded down to the value of `x*y`. This would work perfectly if `x*y` is a float, however, if `x*y` is an integer say, 6, then `v` could be either be 5 or 6. To avoid such cases, one could introduce a small constant tolerance `e > 0` and apply it to one of the inequalities.

Below is a short code snippet to demonstrate the above reasoning:

```
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB

m = gp.Model()

x = m.addVar(vtype = GRB.CONTINUOUS, ub = 5)
y = m.addVar(vtype = GRB.CONTINUOUS, ub = 8)

int_var = m.addVar(vtype = GRB.INTEGER)

# fix x, y to some float values.
# x*y = 27.8695, so int_var should = 27, post solve 
m.addConstr(x == 4.01)
m.addConstr(y == 6.95)

e = 0.00001

m.addConstr(x*y >= int_var - e)
m.addConstr(x*y <= int_var + 1 - e)

# dummy objective, since x and y are already fixed
m.setObjective(x*y, sense = GRB.MAXIMIZE)

m.optimize()
```

Indeed, `int_var` resolves to `27` which is the floor of `x*y = 27.8695`.
If you take `x*y=24`, the `int_var` will resolve to `24` (which is expected behaviour, per small tolerance `e` taken above.

Comment: The floor function of an integer is the integer itself.

Comment: Yes, you are right, may be i need to word my answer to reflect that. Essentially, my point was if x*y resolved to integer (say, 6), then there are 2 possibilities : int_var = 6 => 6 <= 6 <= 7 or int_var = 5 => 5 <= 6 <= 6. Wanted to pick on of these by adding the small tolerance.